# How do I make a React Native Image component adjust view bounds on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I have the following `Image` component paired with two `Text` elements in a React Native flexbox:

```
<View
    style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    }}>
    <Image
       style={{
           width: 100,
           height: undefined,
           margin: 4,
           // borderWidth: 1,
           // borderColor: '#777',
       }}
       source={{uri: image.url}}
       resizeMode='center'
    />
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{article.promotionContent.title.value}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.description}>{article.promotionContent.description.value}</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

It porduces this output when implemented as above:

[image]

However I suspect that it doesn't [adjust view bounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) since I get white space above the image (it's supposed to align to the top) and if I add borders to the `View`, i.e. uncommenting the two lines, I get this weird artifact:

[image]

Have anyone else experienced this?

If you want to test my project, check out commit `3a3f705c271a0b523a1769536d16984c5dd47233` in [this repo](https://github.com/Nilzor/newsapp)

My question is somewhat laden with assumptions. My end goal is to rescale height after having set a constant width, add border and top align.